# Running an Excel Macro in Sharepoint? Is it possible?

Tags: sharepoint, excel, vba

I have an Excel file with a Macro that connects to an Oracle Database, runs a query and returns the results in a Spreadsheet in the same Excel file.

I'd like to run that Macro from Sharepoint. Is it possible? If so, what's the way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Sharepoint Excel services can handle this macro, your option would be to create a sharepoint list with same fields as that of Excel spreadsheet and connect it to your oracle database using BCS (Business Connectivity Services) feature. You can do this task using Sharepoint designer.